# LINK не может найти библиотеку при сборке проекта CMAKE

Tags: c++, qt5, cmake

Есть затык в написании cmake файла для мультиплатформенной сборки. Подробности:
Разбиваю проект на несколько библиотек для простоты работы. Выношу библиотеку доступа к БД в отдельную dll. Сразу оговорюсь - все модули работают если находятся в теле основной программы, то есть ошибок там нет (пока что :) )

Для сборки проекта создал новый cmake-проект, который включается как подпроект в основной:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(plgconnector LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

if (WIN32)
    message("[PLG CONNECTOR] Build Windows revision!")
    find_package(QT NAMES Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets Core svg REQUIRED)
    find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Core svg Widgets REQUIRED)
    find_package(PostgreSQL REQUIRED)
endif(WIN32)

if (UNIX AND NOT APPLE)
    message("[PLG CONNECTOR] Build Linux revision!")
    find_package(QT NAMES Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Widgets REQUIRED)
    find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Core Widgets REQUIRED)
    find_package(PostgreSQL REQUIRED)
endif()

message("[PLG CONNECTOR] PostgreSQL VER: " ${PostgreSQL_VERSION_STRING})
message("[PLG CONNECTOR] Include files PostgreSQL: " ${PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message("[PLG CONNECTOR] Lib files PostgreSQL: " ${PostgreSQL_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_library(plgconnector SHARED
  plgconnector_global.h
  tconnector.cpp
  tnotifyer.cpp
  tquery.cpp
  treader.cpp
  tconnector.h
  pgerror.ui
  pgerror.h
  pgerror.cpp
  sqlhighlighter.h
  sqlhighlighter.cpp
  sqlloghlighter.h
  sqlloghlighter.cpp
)

include_directories(AFTER ${PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(AFTER ${PostgreSQL_LIBRARY_DIRS} ${PLG_LIB})

if (WIN32)
    target_link_libraries(plgconnector Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets
        "${PostgreSQL_LIBRARY_DIRS}/libpq.lib"
    )
endif(WIN32)

if (UNIX AND NOT APPLE)
    target_link_libraries(plgconnector Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets pq)
endif()

target_compile_definitions(plgconnector PRIVATE PLGCONNECTOR_LIBRARY)

set_target_properties(plgconnector PROPERTIES
    ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${PlatformDir}"
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${PlatformDir}"
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${PlatformDir}"
)
```

приведенный текст проекта работает как надо, но есть вопрос. Ранее в основном проекте я писал

```
if (WIN32)
    target_link_libraries(plgconnector Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets libpq
    )
endif(WIN32)
```

и проект вполне себе нормально собирался и собирается, все нормально. Но если я тут пишу просто libpq, то на стадии линковки мне вываливает ошибку, что - файл не найден, но если я задаю путь напрямую - то все нормально. Причем этот косяк только для WIN32, в Linux все собирается нормально.

Не могу понять, что я делаю не так. Ведь есть код добавления:

```
link_directories(AFTER ${PostgreSQL_LIBRARY_DIRS} ${PLG_LIB})
```

У кого есть мысли?

**UPD:** Для сборки в винде используется MS VC 2022.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Команда `link_directories` влияет только на таргеты, созданные **после** неё.
Так как у Вас в коде таргет `plgconnector` создаётся (вызовом `add_library`) до вызова `link_directories`, то директории поиска библиотек не добавляются.

Один из вариантов решения - перенос вызова `link_directories` до создания таргета:

```
link_directories(AFTER ${PostgreSQL_LIBRARY_DIRS} ${PLG_LIB})
...
add_library(plgconnector SHARED ...)
...
target_link_libraries(plgconnector Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets
  libpq
)
```

Но вообще, использование `link_directories` не рекомендуется, а предпочтительно как раз передавать полные пути в `target_link_libraries`. Если не хотите хардкодить расширении библиотеки libpq, то можно выполнить поиск библиотеки в заданных директориях:

```
add_library(plgconnector SHARED ...)
# Ищем библиотеку libpq, используя директорию PostgreSQL_LIBRARY_DIRS в качестве подсказки
find_library(LIBRARY_PQ libpq HINTS ${PostgreSQL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
#
target_link_libraries(plgconnector Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets
  ${LIBRARY_PQ}
)
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Перечитал документацию по данной функции, видимо невнимательно читал ранее.

Comment: Чтобы не заниматься ерундой, прочитайте документацию по https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.28/module/FindPostgreSQL.html и не придется ничего руками искать и писать. Линковщику нудно передать `PostgreSQL::PostgreSQL`.